# How to set up app testing for a BLU DASH Jr Phone Androiid version 2.3.5

Tags: android

I'm a MAC user and I bought this phone specifically for app testing. The instructions for setting it up (link provided) only get me so far because there's no select option on this particular phone explicitly called "build number" in the settings which I'm supposed to tap to open developer options. 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice
[image]

Comment: Settings-> About Phone-> Build number ( tap 7 time).
Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7xIvgyaO4M) video.

Comment: my phone doesn't have the build number option in the settings. I explain in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can be of help:
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/55891

> Back in Android 2.3, you just need to go to Settings - Applications - Development.